# Inno Setup Crashes frequently when run in silent mode

Tags: crash, inno-setup

So I run my installer with the following command:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Example\ExampleSetup.exe /VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NORESTART
```

But for some strange reason the installer has a 50% chance of failure and when it does fail it returns a random exit code from 0-3.
I think this might be because of the `/VERYSILENT` because I never witnessed this behavior when running it non-silently.
I also use `SetupMutex` in the `[Setup]` section, so could this be the case that its crashing half of the time?
I also would like to get meaningful exit code if process does crash so I could debug the problem.
**This is the log output:**

```
2016-05-02 11:33:01.421   Log opened. (Time zone: UTC+03:00)
2016-05-02 11:33:01.421   Setup version: Inno Setup version 5.5.6 (u)
2016-05-02 11:33:01.421   Original Setup EXE: C:\Program Files (x86)\Maprinter\MaprinterSetup.exe
2016-05-02 11:33:01.421   Setup command line: /SL5="$F403AE,242855,184832,C:\Program Files (x86)\Maprinter\MaprinterSetup.exe" /VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NORESTART "/LOG=C:\Program Files (x86)\Maprinter\MaprinterSetup.log" Restart
2016-05-02 11:33:01.421   Windows version: 10.0.10586  (NT platform: Yes)
2016-05-02 11:33:01.421   64-bit Windows: Yes
2016-05-02 11:33:01.421   Processor architecture: x64
2016-05-02 11:33:01.421   User privileges: Administrative
2016-05-02 11:33:01.422   64-bit install mode: No
2016-05-02 11:33:01.425   Created temporary directory: C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\is-SM12R.tmp
2016-05-02 11:33:01.494   Extracting temporary file: C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\is-SM12R.tmp\InnoCallback.dll
2016-05-02 11:33:01.593   Extracting temporary file: C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\is-SM12R.tmp\unzipper.dll
2016-05-02 11:33:01.723   Exception message:
2016-05-02 11:33:01.723   Defaulting to OK for suppressed message box (OK):
                          Error reading WelcomeLabel2.Caption: System Error.  Code: 1411.
                          Class does not exist.
2016-05-02 11:33:01.723   Deinitializing Setup.
2016-05-02 11:33:01.728   Log closed.
```

**This is a different log output for the same problem:**

```
2016-05-02 12:04:50.495   Log opened. (Time zone: UTC+03:00)
2016-05-02 12:04:50.495   Setup version: Inno Setup version 5.5.6 (u)
2016-05-02 12:04:50.495   Original Setup EXE: C:\Program Files (x86)\Maprinter\MaprinterSetup.exe
2016-05-02 12:04:50.495   Setup command line: /SL5="$177016C,242855,184832,C:\Program Files (x86)\Maprinter\MaprinterSetup.exe" /VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NORESTART /LOG=C:\Users\yuvadius\Desktop\MaprinterSetup.log Restart
2016-05-02 12:04:50.495   Windows version: 10.0.10586  (NT platform: Yes)
2016-05-02 12:04:50.495   64-bit Windows: Yes
2016-05-02 12:04:50.495   Processor architecture: x64
2016-05-02 12:04:50.495   User privileges: Administrative
2016-05-02 12:04:50.496   64-bit install mode: No
2016-05-02 12:04:50.500   Created temporary directory: C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\is-NFR0Q.tmp
2016-05-02 12:04:50.528   Extracting temporary file: C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\is-NFR0Q.tmp\InnoCallback.dll
2016-05-02 12:04:50.607   Extracting temporary file: C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\is-NFR0Q.tmp\unzipper.dll
2016-05-02 12:04:50.763   Exception message:
2016-05-02 12:04:50.763   Defaulting to OK for suppressed message box (OK):
                          System Error.  Code: 8.
                          Not enough storage is available to process this command.
2016-05-02 12:04:50.763   Deinitializing Setup.
2016-05-02 12:04:50.770   Log closed.
```

So my concrete question is: Why is my installer crashing frequently and what can I do to solve this?

Comment: At what stage does it crash? Show us log file and your full script.

Comment: The installer does not create a log file.

Comment: This is my full script if you need, http://textuploader.com/5yi0l

Comment: OK, good. Is this consistent? Do you get the same error (Error reading WelcomeLabel2.Caption) everytime the installer crashes? Now go add `Log` call at the start of every function/procedure in your code and post a new log.

Comment: Is there anyway to overwrite the Log which each execution of the installer because I find myself erasing the log each time.

Comment: Inno Setup overwrites the log itself, at least it does for me. Try to log to user-writable folder (e.g. desktop), instead of to "program files"

Comment: Btw, I cannot reproduce the crash. Windows 10. I've tried both Inno Setup 5.5.9 and 5.5.6.

Comment: I'm surprised u could run it, i use many plugins and stuff and as i said this error occurs sometimes. From some computers it occurs more frequently then others.

Comment: Should I consider upgrading from inno setup 5.5.6 to 5.5.9?

Comment: You should always use the latest version. Particularly the 5.5.9 fixes an important security issue. But I do not think it resolves your problem.

Comment: + I've downloaded all the plugins. I've run the installer dozen times. No crash.

Comment: I see that the second log has a different error. Though the installation phase is the same and both errors indicate an overwritten memory. So now try to locate the crash more closely using the `Log`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by temporarily removing the "timer" stuff.

Chances are that the timer expires at about a time the quick silent installation is finishing, so the `mytimerproc` is trying to access a window that no longer exists or the pascal script is engine being destroyed.

If this proves to be the case (and actually even if not), you should fix these issues:

- you need to destroy the timer when the installer is closing (maybe from `CurStepChanged(ssDone)`)
- you possibly do not even want to schedule the timer in very silent installations, as there's no form to make transparent.
- you should schedule the timer in `InitializeWizard`, not in `InitializeSetup`, as you risk the window not even existing yet otherwise, when the timer expires, if the installer is starting slowly.

Comment: I still have the same issue but I will definitely implement your suggestions.

Comment: OK, then we need to see the log to know when the crash occurs. Though in general, you should start by removing code piece by piece  to find out which causes the crash. Or at least add some logging ([`Log` function](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_log)) in every function of yours to help debugging.